# Question on series alternating

Tags: calculus

Let a be a positive integer. Determine the smallest value of a such that the series $$\sum_{n-1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{n+ln(n)}{n^a}$$ is convergent
I came across 2 answers for this question and unsure which one is correct. a = 1 or 2.
Unsure how it works too. Please advice. Thank you

**My workings**

[image]

Comment: for $a=1$ the general term does not even go to zero...